# How do I “read” multiple variables on a while loop

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop

How can I read from multiple variables with a while read line? I'm trying to create a csv file from these variables which are multi-lined.

Not sure if this the best way to do this.

For example:

```
1st_list=$(..code..)
2nd_list=$(..code..)

while read line_from_1, line_from_2
do
    echo "$line_from_1,$line_from_2" >> outputfile.csv

done < $1st_list,$2nd_list
```

Comment: What are sample values in `$1st_list` and `$2nd_list`?

Comment: @anubhava $1st_list and $2nd_list are script variables which are multi-lined. I'm trying to create a csv file with these variables. Not sure if this is the best way to do this.  I'll update the question.

Comment: You have two sets of lines that you are trying to combine how exactly? `line1,line2`? `line1field1,line2field1,l1f2,l2f2,....'?

Comment: Move the `>>outputfile.csv` from the `echo` to a `>outputfile.csv` after the `done` -- that way you open the output file only once, rather than re-opening it (and then closing it) every single time you want to write a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want as output

```
file1line1,file2line1
file2line2,file2line2
etc.
```

then you don't need anything like this at all as `paste` does exactly that.

```
paste -d, <(echo "$first_list") <(echo "$second_list")
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a little unclear, but in order to read from multiple sources in parallel, you need to use multiple file descriptors and, I think, process substitution.

```
while read line_from_1; 
      read -u 3 line_from_2; do
    echo "From first: $line_from_1"
    echo "From second: $line_from_2"
done < <( echo "$first_list" ) 3< <(echo "$second_list")
```

(Of course, you don't have to use the two variables if they aren't preexisting; just put the code that populates each variable in the appropriate process substitution that feeds the `while` loop:

```
done < <( ...code for first list...) 3< <(...code for second list...)
```

)

As written, the loop will succeed as long as the *second* read succeeds (the exit status of the first read is ignored). To loop as long as both succeed, use `read line_from_1 && read -u 3 line_from_2`.

To loop as long as *either* succeeds, you'll need a slightly more complicated mini script as the `while` condition:

```
while read line_from_1; read1=$?;
      read line_from_2; read2=$?;
      (( read1 == 0 || read2 == 0 )); do
```

UPDATE: you can also simply use here strings if the variables are already set in place of the process substitutions. (I wasn't sure if `3<<<` was legal.)

```
while read line_from_1; read -u 3 line_from_2; do
    ...
done <<< "$first_line" 3<<< "$second_line"
```

Comment: That fails when `$first_list` is emptied.

Comment: Yes; there are multiple ways you can handle when one or the other list is exhausted first, and the OP hasn't mentioned in the question what the desired behavior is.

Comment: Better, of course, to replace the `echo "$first_list"` and `echo "$second_list"` with the code that actually generates them; that way the content doesn't need to be stored in memory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll make that more explicit.

Comment: Also, the POSIX way to read from something other than standard input is with `read line_from_2 <&3`. We've already ditched POSIX compliance by using process substitutions, so I'll leave the fix for that (using here-documents containing command substitutions or using explicit named pipes) as an exercise for the reader.